# Seleccionar columnas

Tags: r

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente df

```
datos2<-data.frame( col1=c("WWW","CCC","PPP"),
                    col2=c("AAA","BBB","AAA"),
                    col3=c("XXX","YYY","ZZZ"))
```

y creo una función donde el usuario pueda indicar las columnas a unir

```
union <- function(x,y) {
  unir=c(x,y)
  datos2 %>% unite("Union",all_of(unir), sep=" ",remove=T)
}
```

De manera que el usario puede hacer:

```
union("col1","col2")
union("col1","col3")
```

Si tengo un df con 200 columnas

-¿Cómo modifico function(x,y) para poder meter cualquier número de columnas?

-¿Qué tendría que poner el usuario para indicar que quiere unir todas las columnas?

-¿y si quiere unir todas las columnas menos la 34 y la 145?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cómo modifico function(x,y) para poder meter cualquier número de columnas?

Recuerda que en R, cualquier variable es al menos un vector, por lo que hacer

```
union <- function(x,y) {..}
```

Dónde `x` e `y` eventualmente podrían tener cualquier cantidad de valores, es practicamente lo mismo que hacer:

```
union <- function(columnas) {
  datos2 %>% unite("Union",all_of(columnas), sep=" ",remove=T)
}
```

dónde la ejecución se haría:

```
union(c("col1","col2"))
```

> ¿Qué tendría que poner el usuario para indicar que quiere unir todas
> las columnas?

```
union(colnames(datos2))
```

> -¿y si quiere unir todas las columnas menos la 34 y la 145?

```
union(colnames(datos2)[-c(34,145)])
```

Ahora bien, te recuerdo que también estas mismas operaciones de selección pueden hacerse de una manera mas clara, directamente desde los ["select helpers"](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html) de `tidyselect` que estás usando. Por ejemplo:

```
unite(datos2, "Union", col1, col2, sep=" ", remove=T)     # col1 + col2
unite(datos2, "Union", col1:col3, sep=" ", remove=T)      # De col1 a col3
unite(datos2, "Union", everything(), sep=" ", remove=T)   # Todas las columnas
unite(datos2, "Union", sep=" ", remove=T)                 # Todas las columnas
unite(datos2, "Union", -col1, -col2, sep=" ", remove=T)   # Todas -col1 y -col2
```